# Automatic mounting RAID array which is mounted manually

Tags: server, mount, raid, fstab, mdadm

For our server setup, we have a RAID array which is being setup once and we have actually never rebooted the server. Right now the array is working fine, but I would like to add its entry to fstab so it's mounted automatically. I just don't know how to do that, as I can see the entry in mdadm.conf. The raid array is mounted on /dev/md1.

Output of mount command :

```
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=4108136,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,size=3287872k,mode=755)
/dev/disk/by-uuid/ae73679c-c3cd-4a60-bcbb-5b6ddce867f7 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,data=ordered)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /run/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=9931180k)
/dev/sdc2 on /boot type ext3 (rw,relatime,errors=continue,user_xattr,acl,barrier=1,data=ordered)
/dev/md1 on /media/attachment type ext4 (rw,relatime,user_xattr,barrier=1,stripe=256,data=ordered)
```

Contents of /etc/fstab file :

```
proc /proc proc defaults 0 0
# /dev/sdc1 during Installation (RescueSystem)
UUID=b678077b-314c-4e2f-84ed-a3d0b3ded812 none swap sw 0 0
# /dev/sdc2 during Installation (RescueSystem)
UUID=12c0304a-21cc-4b4b-ac35-2352766620b3 /boot ext3 defaults 0 0
# /dev/sdc3 during Installation (RescueSystem)
UUID=ae73679c-c3cd-4a60-bcbb-5b6ddce867f7 / ext4 defaults 0 0
```

contents of mdadm.conf :

```
# mdadm.conf
#
# Please refer to mdadm.conf(5) for information about this file.
#

# by default (built-in), scan all partitions (/proc/partitions) and all
# containers for MD superblocks. alternatively, specify devices to scan, using
# wildcards if desired.
#DEVICE partitions containers

# auto-create devices with Debian standard permissions
CREATE owner=root group=disk mode=0660 auto=yes

# automatically tag new arrays as belonging to the local system
HOMEHOST <system>

# instruct the monitoring daemon where to send mail alerts
MAILADDR root

# definitions of existing MD arrays
ARRAY /dev/md/0 metadata=1.2 UUID=067051b2:ff104bec:e0744d08:76a99a32 name=rescue:0
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=b847912c:37f51b40:db18e3d7:579b580e name=rescue:1
ARRAY /dev/md/2 metadata=1.2 UUID=9a844938:07bf4ec4:73edaa03:c703df5d name=rescue:2

# This configuration was auto-generated on Mon, 25 Aug 2014 15:25:21 +0200
# by mkconf 3.2.5-5
ARRAY /dev/md/1 metadata=1.2 UUID=68e853a6:7af46176:d9c147c7:6ff87bb0 name=company:1
```

Kindly let me know what I should do. Thanks a lot. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My mdraid drive is in the /etc/fstab file mounted by UUID, with a note added by the installation:

```
# / was on /dev/md127 during installation
UUID=a7e381c3-8336-4768-b77b-79faf573dc20 /               ext3    errors=remount-ro 0       1
```

The UUID matches the one given by the command

```
blkid /dev/md127
```

(and not the UUID in mdadm.conf!) so that looks like the way it can be identified for mounting.

By the way, my system has another array that is only exported through iSCSI and not locally mounted - it appears in mdadm.conf but not in /etc/fstab.

Comment: The problem is solved, i was able to directly put data in fstab with defaults.